# PHPのバージョンを指定してLaravelのプロジェクトを作成したい

Tags: php, laravel, composer

### 前提

PHP 5.6, Laravel 4.2.11 を使用してプロジェクトを作成したいと考えております.

---

### 発生している問題

以下のコマンドを入力して Laravel 4.2.22 のプロジェクトを作成しました.

```sh
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist PROJECT_NAME 4.2.22
```

しかし、こちらで作成したプロジェクトにはどうやら PHP 7.1 が使われているようです.
Eclipse で作成したプロジェクトを確認すると、 PHP Language Library [PHP 7.1] と表示されます.

composer には使用する PHP に PHP 5.6 を登録したのですが、何故か PHP 7.1 で作成されてしまいます.

Eclipse からプロジェクトを作成することはできるのですが、 Eclipse で開発したいとは考えておりませんので、コマンドプロンプトから PHP, Laravel のバージョンを指定してプロジェクトを作成したいです.

また、 composer に PHP 5.6 を登録する以前に PHP 7.1 を登録したことがあります.
composer をアンインストールし、改めて登録をやり直したほうが良いのでしょうか？

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

- Windows 10
- PHP 5.6.32 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2017 16:00:49)
- Laravel Framework version 4.2.22
- Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25
- `composer.json`:

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/commands",
                        "app/controllers",
                        "app/models",
                        "app/database/migrations",
                        "app/database/seeds",
                        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
                ]
        },  "scripts": {
                "post-install-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "php artisan key:generate"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "stable"  
}
```

Comment: 作成されたconposer.jsonファイルを転記していただくことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @keitaro_so コメントありがとうございます！前回の質問でもお世話になりましたm(_ _*)m
composer.jsonファイルの内容を追記にて記載致しましたので、ご確認ください.